# How to write a test case to verify log4j logs are generated in proper format

Tags: java, testing, junit, automated-tests, integration-testing

I want to write a testng test case to verify that the logs (log4j) generated are following exactly the given conversion pattern from the log4j.properties file. As an example if I have conversion pattern : `[%d] %-5p [%t]: %m%n` a sample log would looks like `[2015-07-07 16:42:09,937] DEBUG [main]: Message 1` I want to make sure that the log follows the exact pattern.

So for now what I'm doing is first read all the logs in to a String array and loop that array to find whether the expected log without the date i.e. `DEBUG [main]: Message 1` contains in the recorded.

Is this way of testing log records is correct ?
If you have any idea about a good way to test logs rather than this please point out.

Comment: You could use a mocking framework (mockito, easymock, or similar) to create a mocked logger. Which logging framework are you using? Could you provide a minimal example, that logs "Message 1"?

Comment: I'm using log4j as logging back end and apache commons logging API

Comment: "following exactly the given conversion pattern from the log4j.properties file" that sounds more like trying to test log4j than your own code.

Answer (score 0):

There are any solutions. The first in my mind is:

Configure your `log4j` to write on `System.out` and use the `SystemOutRule`.

```
public void MyTest {
 @Rule
 public final SystemOutRule systemOutRule = new SystemOutRule().enableLog();

 @Test
 public void writesTextToSystemOut() {
   System.out.print("hello world");
   assertEquals("hello world", systemOutRule.getLog());
 }
}
```

See: https://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules/index.html

This solution is logger implementation independent if the logger writes to `System.out` and/or `System.err`.

Comment: I'm writing test cases for a server. Log generation part is ok. I want only the test scenario.

Comment: Use the logger instead of `System.out` in example above or call the server function.

Comment: Already logs are recording in the file system and in the console I don't want to regenerate those logs. I just want to check those logs.

Comment: You don't need to regenerate the logs. The `SystemOurRule` catching all content from `System.out` (console) and provides in test. There is a `SystemErrRule` too.

Answer (score 0):

More `log4J` aware:

Use a mock framework - @slartidan says - and mock the appender implementation.

Based on your preferred mock framework and `log4J 1.x` or `log4J 2.x` the solution is quite different.

**Log4J 1.2**

Create a mock logger appender and add this appender on logger:
`Logger.getLogger("...").addAppender( mockedAppender );`

See: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Category.html#addAppender%28org.apache.log4j.Appender%29

**Log4J 2.x**

Extending `ConfigurationFactory` and `Configuration` (only in test artefact) and add the mocked appender.

> The easiest way to create a custom Configuration is to extend one of the standard Configuration classes (XMLConfiguration, JSONConfiguration) and then create a new ConfigurationFactory for the extended class. After the standard configuration completes the custom configuration can be added to it.

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html (includes complete example)